# Why is this protected member not accessible from the derived class?

Tags: c++, access-specifier

I thought that protected members in a base class are accessible from a derived class, but not so:

```
template <typename T>
class SharedPointer
{
protected:
    explicit SharedPointer(T* const ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}

public:
    constexpr SharedPointer() : ptr(nullptr) { }

protected:
    T* ptr; 
};

template <typename T>
class WeakPointer : public SharedPointer<T>
{
protected:
    using parent_t = SharedPointer<T>;
    WeakPointer(T* ptr) : parent_t(ptr) {   }
public:
    WeakPointer(const WeakPointer& other)
    {
    }
    WeakPointer(WeakPointer&& other) = delete;
    WeakPointer(const SharedPointer<T>& other)
    {
        this->ptr = other.ptr;
    }    
};    

int main()
{
    SharedPointer<int> sp;
    WeakPointer<int> wp = sp;
}
```

The error I get is:

> 'SharedPointer<int>::ptr': cannot access protected member declared in class 'SharedPointer<int>'

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes `protected` is not that intiutive. From [Access specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) on cppreference:

> A protected member of a class is only accessible
>
> 1. to the members and friends of that class;
> 2. to the members of any derived class of that class, but only when the class of the object through which the protected member is accessed is that derived class or a derived class of that derived class:

And then follows an example.

In your case, 2) means that `WeakPointer<T>` can only acces `ptr` via a `WeakPointer<T>` object. If it could access `ptr` through a reference to a `SharedPointer<T>` then it could access `ptr` of a different derived class. And that's what the rules are made to avoid.

---

In this particular case, you do not actually need to access `ptr` in the derived class:

```
WeakPointer(const SharedPointer<T>& other) : SharedPointer<T>(other)
{}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z3PqWrEnd)

Comment: What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: The first thought that came to mind was using a member initializer list to copy-construct the `SharedPointer<T>` base class. But it kind of raises the question of whether it actually makes sense for `WeakPointer` to inherit from `SharedPointer` to begin with.

Comment: @NathanPierson my idea too and then I didnt bother to think more :P Not sure if it actually makes sense. Compiles and is *correct* though